# Applying CSS to elements within a <div>

Tags: css, css-float

I have the following HTML code,

```
<div class="part">
    <div class="pleft">
        <img src="images/1.jpg">
        <b>Image 1</b>
    </div>
    <div class="pright">
        <img src="images/2.jpg">
        <b>Image 2</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I apply CSS styles for the image and b element under *pleft* and *pright*.

Right now I'm doing it the following way,

```
<div class="part">
    <div class="pleft">
        <img class="pl1" src="images/1.jpg">
        <b class="pl2">Image 1</b>
    </div>
    <div class="pright">
        <img class="pr1" src="images/2.jpg">
        <b class="pr2">Image 2</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was wondering if there's any short way to do it. The divs *pright* and *pleft* run pretty long and I don't want to define a new class for each one of them.

Appreciate your help.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS will look like this

```
.pleft {//your css}
.pleft img {//your css}
.pleft b {//your css}

.pright{//your css}
.pright img{//your css}
.pright b{//your css}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.pleft img, .pright img {

   //your CSS for image
}

.pleft b, .pright b {

   //your CSS for b element
}
```

Use it and you not to need to add any other class.

Answer (score 0):

My CSS is not the strongest but, I am assuming you are asking how you can define pleft and pleft with out having to redefine then twice.

So here is how i would do it.

```
.pleft,.pright{ ADD ALL COMMON CSS HERE}
.pleft{ Difference }
.pright{ Difference }
```

You can Apply the same to the sub elements

```
.pleft .pr1,.pright .pr1{ADD ALL COMMON CSS HERE}
.pleft .pr1{ Difference }
.pright .pr1{ Difference }
```

or you can do something like

```
.pleft img,.pright img{ADD ALL COMMON CSS HERE}
.pleft img{ Difference }
.pright img{ Difference }
```

Hope this helps